# reject reason: Low difficulty share

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, ccminer

I've researched the forum and google and it says this means I am using the wrong algorithm, as far as I know graft (v8) works with monero right ?
This is my first time mining using ccminer and the command I have is as follows:

```
ccminer-x64 -a graft -o stratum+tcp://xmr-asia1.nanopool.org:14444 -u 47XbbJdJgYbRKrAK88dUe68ZJkbBhZN5WB7gDo43ViocDjpeeZrRgEgeVpgwCqXWQGD5z3YPkrZR3YknFS5sRozKRxyzdJt -p x
pause
```

I am always getting the following output:

```
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] Using JSON-RPC 2.0
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] Starting on stratum+tcp://xmr-asia1.nanopool.org:14444
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] NVML GPU monitoring enabled.
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] NVAPI GPU monitoring enabled.
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] 1 miner thread started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
[2018-06-22 17:59:27] Stratum difficulty set to 120001 (120.001)
[2018-06-22 17:59:28] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1080, 6808 MB available, 20 SMX
[2018-06-22 17:59:28] GPU #0: 1280 threads (10.25) with 80 blocks
[2018-06-22 17:59:44] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1080, 479.53 H/s
[2018-06-22 17:59:44] GPU #0: 1887 MHz 5.63 H/W 85W 54C FAN 43%
[2018-06-22 18:02:04] GPU #0: 1887 MHz 5.17 H/W 92W 65C FAN 52%
[2018-06-22 18:02:11] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1080, 479.83 H/s
[2018-06-22 18:02:11] accepted: 0/1 (diff 2949.820), 479.68 H/s booooo
[2018-06-22 18:02:11] reject reason: Low difficulty share
[2018-06-22 18:04:23] GPU #0: 1885 MHz 5.09 H/W 94W 68C FAN 55%
[2018-06-22 18:04:41] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1080, 494.80 H/s
[2018-06-22 18:05:38] GPU #0: 1885 MHz 5.08 H/W 95W 69C FAN 56%
[2018-06-22 18:07:44] GPU #0: 1873 MHz 5.14 H/W 94W 69C FAN 57%
[2018-06-22 18:09:01] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1080, 499.58 H/s
[2018-06-22 18:09:02] GPU #0: 1873 MHz 5.15 H/W 94W 69C FAN 58%
[2018-06-22 18:09:02] accepted: 0/2 (diff 631.379), 488.43 H/s booooo
[2018-06-22 18:09:02] reject reason: Low difficulty share
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong algorithm. Monero (XMR) uses cryptonight. However, I'm unaware that ccminer has been updated for v7 (the latest version). I suggest using software the pool recommends / supports.

Answer (score 0):

Monero uses Cryptonight variant 1 as its PoW hash. Some software calls it "Cryptonight V7", because it was introduced at version 7 of the protocol. You need to use that hash algorithm in order to produce shares which meet the requested difficulty.

No idea what graft does though, but I suspect it's not the same thing.